# How to merge two characters imported from MakeHuman

Tags: modeling, makehuman

I started Blender last week and I managed to create my characters in MakeHuman (V 1.0.2), import it to Blender (V 2.76b) and pose these two characters as I want.

Now I want to use them in another scene where they should show up as **one** object which I can place, rotate, scale, etc. This new object should show up just as the two characters in the original scene.

I tried to join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> but this does not work - it even breaks the characters and give some weird structures. I think this is due to the internal structure of the imported characters from MakeHuman.

If I just take them as a copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) they stay as they are, but I have to position/scale them separately which is a lot of work.

Any ideas or hints for me? Please! Thank's in advance.

edit:  just figured out how to attach screen shots.... so here are the screen shots mentioned below in the comments: the first shows the two characters selected with two times [a] and the second after joining them with [ctrl] + [j]

[image: selecting]
[image]

Maybe the problem is, that I do not select the characters properly?

Comment: The details you should include in question are screenshots of what happens after joining objects, what modifiers are added (if any), and if possible [upload a .blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). There are too many possible problems to discuss as for now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit as well as for the response - I just prepared a sample blend-file (early stage in order to make it more clear). When I am trying  Ctrl+J the two characters merge together in one position - only the spines stay where they should.

Comment: Sorry but I could not upload the blend-file (even with compress it has 30.6 MB) so I try it with two screen shots and the file with only one character inside. I apologize too for the second edit, but the system reminded I have only 5 minutes...

Comment: sorry again - uploading is not as easy as I expected  ;-) => this should be the link: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=953" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/953/) and I was not able to upload the screen shots (seems only *.blend files are allowed).

Answer (score 1):

You can parent <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> one of the models to the other or both of them to an empty. And then the transformations should be applied to both of them.

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/relationships/parents.html

Comment: Thanks - but I still can not work it out - I can select the first character without problems, but when I try to select the second, I always end up with one part of it (eg: body or proxy or something else).
Is there something like a "root" of the characters I have to select?

Comment: If your other character is composed of loose parts you probably first want to select them all and join them normally.

Comment: Sorry no - I did not, since I believed that this has alredy been done by the export/import filter (mhx2). Grouping was the solution also for this problem - as it turned out in this question <http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46320/newbie-merge-characters-and-scenes-how-to-do-with-make-human-characters?noredirect=1#comment78621_46320>

Answer (score 0):

As described in my commend above my solution was to group the characters within the original file and append them by the group.

Answer (score 0):

Hi were you able to get the solution?
Even I have been trying to join but final model is all mixed up with no proper form

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.